# Sorting a list of objects with it's parameter

Tags: .net, linq

I'm trying to sort a list of objects in a particular order.

```
Dim myList as new List(Of myObj)
```

`myObj` has 2 parameters `Name` (string) and `ParentName` (string)

Let's say `myList` has n number of items and they are in the following order:

```
myList(0): Name="MD" , ParentName = ""  
myList(1): Name="Operations Manager" , ParentName = "MD"  
myList(2): Name="Section Sub Manager" , ParentName = "Section Manager"  
myList(3): Name="Assistant Manager1" , ParentName = "Tactical Manager"  
myList(4): Name="Tactical Manager" , ParentName = "MD"  
myList(5): Name="Assistant Manager2" , ParentName = "Tactical Manager"  
myList(6): Name="Section Manager" , ParentName = "MD"
```

I have to sort the above so the child nodes appear AFTER it's parent ie:

```
myList(0): Name="MD" , ParentName = ""  
myList(1): Name="Operations Manager" , ParentName = "MD"  
myList(2): Name="Section Manager" , ParentName = "MD"  
myList(3): Name="Section Sub Manager" , ParentName = "Section Manager" 
myList(4): Name="Tactical Manager" , ParentName = "MD"  
myList(5): Name="Assistant Manager1" , ParentName = "Tactical Manager"  
myList(6): Name="Assistant Manager2" , ParentName = "Tactical Manager"
```

please help.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand, in your sorted list example at the bottom, the items at indices 3 and 4 could be swapped without violating the condition, right?

Comment: yes thats right, as long as parent node is above the children it's ok, the children nodes doesn't have to be right underneath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright then, this seems to be a straightforward custom sort with the twist that the ordering constraint doesn't form a total order (only a partial one). This should do the trick:

```
var sorted = myList.OrderBy(x => x, new CustomComparer()).ToList();

class CustomComparer : IComparer<myObj>
{
    public int Compare(myObj a, myObj b)
    {
        return a.ParentName == b.Name ? 1 : a.Name == b.ParentName ? -1 : 0;
    }
}
```

(Of course, you need to make sure there's no children that are their own grandparents for this to work properly.)